# How to declare templated pointer to templated method?

Tags: c++11, templates, using, pointer-to-member

Templated `typedef`s are possible with `using`. How can I directly make a templated method pointer?

Example:

```
class MyClass {

  template<bool B> void fnc() { /*...*/ };

  // Now I can do:
  template<bool B>
  using TempPtr = decltype(&MyClass::fnc<B>);
  //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

How can I write the underlined part direcly, without `decltype`?

So far, I have tried:

```
template<bool B>
using TempPtr = template<bool> void (MyClass::*)();

template<bool B>
using TempPtr = void (MyClass::*<B>)();

...
```

(Follow up question: Can I use `TempPtr`as a template template parameter?)

Comment: Obligatory "why would you ever want that" :D Anyway, are you sure you need the template part for the actual member function?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I am working on a new metaprogramming pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Those will work, giving slightly different behaviour:

```
template<bool B>
using Ptr = void (MyClass::*)();

using Ptr2 = void (MyClass::*)();

// alternatively
//typedef void (MyClass::*Ptr2)();
```

To use:

```
MyClass::Ptr<true> ptr = &MyClass::fnc<true>;

MyClass::Ptr2 ptr2 = &MyClass::fnc<true>;
```

The bool parameter in `Ptr` isn't the same as the parameter in `fnc`. Since the template type isn't a part of the signature, a mismatch will bind just fine, but could be utilized for other purposes:

```
MyClass::Ptr<false> ptr = &MyClass::fnc<true>;
```

That's also why the nontemplated `Ptr2` also works fine.